# Jmeter API testing using csv input as post request in localhost

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

I tried to run a POST method for API testing in JMeter, I have sent the parameters as needed in body using a csv file. It works with https url(domain url) but not working in localhost. In localhost, requested body is showing blank. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no any difference between local and non-local URLs so most probably you made a configuration mistake somewhere. We cannot state where exactly without seeing the test plan so I would suggest:

1. Inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. Ensure that the variables originating from the CSV Data Set Config really exist and have their respective values by adding a [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and seeing what variables are there.
3. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. If it doesn't say anything meaningful you can try [increasing logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging).